# How to map UIImage, UILabel and UIView contents to a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, tags

A `String` is received from an API call. This string basically defines what `UIImage`, `UILabel` and `UIView`'s tag. There are 9 types of strings that can be received from this API call. I have the following code to map these:

```
struct Map{
var image : UIImage!
var title : String!

func getProperties(stringFromAPI : String) {
    switch stringFromAPI {
    case "fireFS":
        self.image = UIImage(string: "fireFS")
        self.title = "Fire"
    case "chromeFS":
        self.image = UIImage(string: "chrome_FS_1")
        self.title = "Chromatic"
    default:
        break
    }
} }
```

Is there an efficient way of setting all these properties in an enum and retrieving it globally? Any help would be greatly appreciated and upvoted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a global dictionary such as :

```swift
struct ExampleDict {
    static let data: [String: [String: Any]] = [
        "fireFS": [
            "imageName": "fireFS",
            "title": "Fire"
        ],

        "chromeFS": [
            "imageName": "chrome_FS_1",
            "title": "Chromatic"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here you set the key for each tuple as the string you expect from the API, i.e. `stringFromAPI`. Then you can add imageName, title and any other tuples in this.

For retrieving values from the dictionary simply subscript it like an array :

```swift
if let imageName = ExampleDict.data["chromeFS"]?["imageName"] {
    print(imageName)
}
```

Now, let's integrate this with your existing code :

```swift
func getProperties(stringFromAPI : String) {

    if let imageName = ExampleDict.data[stringFromAPI]?["imageName"] {
        print(imageName)
    }

    if let imageTitle = ExampleDict.data[stringFromAPI]?["title"] {
        print(imageTitle)
    }
}
```

Let's try this out...

```swift
getProperties(stringFromAPI: "fireFS")

/// Output
// fireFS
// Fire

getProperties(stringFromAPI: "chromeFS")

/// Output
// chrome_FS_1
// Chromatic
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    enum ImageMapping: String {
        case fireFS = "fireFS"
        case chromeFS = "chromeFS"

        func imageName() -> String {
            switch self {
            case .fireFS:
                return "Fire"
            case .chromeFS:
                return "Chromatic"
            }
        }
    }

    func getProperties(stringFromAPI : String) {
        let mapping = ImageMapping(rawValue: stringFromAPI)
        self.image = UIImage(string: stringFromAPI)
        self.title = mapping?.imageName()

    }
```

Comment: using this answer is it possible to get back the enum's raw value by using its imageName property? This solution looks great so I wanted to clarify if reverse lookup is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to write another function to do that.